# Rails - Active Storage - Validates images certain dimensions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, validation, rails-activestorage

I found [gem activestorage-validator](https://github.com/aki77/activestorage-validator), but is there a way of validating an attached image based on its dimensions?

I essentially want to be able to block a user from attaching an image that can't cleanly be cropped/compressed (i.e. 3000px x 10px).

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You'll probably need to use something like [`minimagick`](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick), activestorage-validator doesn't know about image dimensions.